# Recursive critical section on Windows not working

Tags: multithreading, c++-cx, critical-section

I have the following code written in C++/CX:

```
TaskPool^ TaskPool::Instance::get()
{
    // Prevent acquiring the critical section for a static initialization
    // after it's been properly initialized.
    if (TaskPool::_instance == nullptr) {

        static CRITICAL_SECTION section;

        CriticalSection lock(&section);

        if (TaskPool::_instance == nullptr) {
            _instance = ref new TaskPool();
            InitializeCriticalSection(GetCriticalSection());
        }
    }
    return _instance;
}

TaskPool^ TaskPool::_instance;
CRITICAL_SECTION TaskPool::_criticalSection;

void Threading::TaskPool::TaskRun(Concurrency::task<void> & task)
{
    Log::LogMessage(this->GetType()->FullName, Level::Debug, "TaskRun [entering]");
    EnterCriticalSection(GetCriticalSection());
    Log::LogMessage(this->GetType()->FullName, Level::Debug, "TaskRun [entered]");

    create_task(task).then([this]() {
        Log::LogMessage(this->GetType()->FullName, Level::Debug, "TaskRun [leaving]");
        LeaveCriticalSection(GetCriticalSection());
        Log::LogMessage(this->GetType()->FullName, Level::Debug, "TaskRun [left]");
    });
}
```

`TaskPool` is a task dispatcher that uses a `CRITICAL_SECTION` to dispatch concorrent tasks synchronously. I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7260467/6324895) and confirmed in several other places that critical sections are reentrant. However, I'm failing to replicate this behaviour.

```
Threading.TaskPool <Debug> TaskRun [entering]
Threading.TaskPool <Debug> TaskRun [entered]
Threading.TaskPool <Debug> TaskRun [leaving]
Threading.TaskPool <Debug> TaskRun [left]
Threading.TaskPool <Debug> TaskRun [entering]
Threading.TaskPool <Debug> TaskRun [entering]
```

As you can see several tasks are being dispatched. However, even though the first task seems to work well, other tasks added to the pool are not being dispatched. For some reason, the critical section is not entered and the thread seems to hang. If the critical sections are recursive, what else could explain this behaviour?

Comment: This has nothing to do with reentrancy, I think. It seems that EnterCriticalSection and LeaveCriticalSection are not called on the same thread.

Comment: You're right! I did not notice that. We're looking for ways of changing the paradigm in a way that the same thread would release the lock. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, that depends on the implementation of the task pool. I would rather use a semaphore for synchronization in your case, because it can be released on a different thread.

Comment: Will those be reentrant? If the same thread attempts to acquire the semaphore twice, does it block?

Comment: Semaphores are not reentrant, they're thread-independent.

Comment: However, any code that requires reentrant CS's can be rewritten to require only regular ones.